# Por qué este método de buscar elementos en una lista no entrega ningún valor?

Tags: java, lista, netbeans, arraylist, buscador

no estoy seguro muy bien pero estoy haciendo un menú de usuarios en el netbeans. Eh usado 2 métodos para querer buscar uno para buscar un "producto" y otro para buscar un "Proveedor" y los 2 no me botan ningún valor.

y la cosa es de que al momento de poner el id del proveedor me debe botar todo su informacion, bueno, eh intentado y no me sale. Help meee.

Clase del proveedor:

```
package Atributos;

public class Proveedor {
    private int idprovedor;
    private String razon_social;
    private int ruc;
    private String estado;

    public Proveedor() {
    }

    public Proveedor(int idprovedor, String razon_social, int ruc, String estado) {
        this.idprovedor = idprovedor;
        this.razon_social = razon_social;
        this.ruc = ruc;
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public int getIdprovedor() {
        return idprovedor;
    }

    public void setIdprovedor(int idprovedor) {
        this.idprovedor = idprovedor;
    }

    public String getRazon_social() {
        return razon_social;
    }

    public void setRazon_social(String razon_social) {
        this.razon_social = razon_social;
    }

    public int getRuc() {
        return ruc;
    }
```

Ahora bien, el menú principal es este:

```
package control;

import Atributos.Producto;
import Atributos.Proveedor;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import Util2.Lectura;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class menu {

    private static Lectura leer = new Lectura();
    public static ArrayList<Proveedor> proveedores = new ArrayList<>();

public static void buscar_proveedor() {
        
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println(" Buscar Proveedor");
        System.out.println(" ");
        String Buscar;
        System.out.print("Ingrese el ID a buscar: ");
        Buscar=teclado.next();
        if(BuscarElemento(proveedores,Buscar)){
            System.out.println("PROVEEDOR ENCONTRADO");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO EXISTE");
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Cómo está definido el ArrayList `proveedores`? Todo indica que puedes estar usando un tipo de dato incorrecto

Comment: Hola, eh reestructurado mi pregunta..

Comment: Borraste el método `BuscarElemento`. E igual, para cuando lo pongas, revisa cómo funciona `contains`. Entregarle un String y decirle que busque entre instancias de Proveedor está complicado... cómo debería buscarlo?

Comment: Vale gracias men, ya me diste una idea c:

Comment: No veo el método ``BuscarElemento``, seguramente ahí esta la falla también no se ve donde llenas el ArrayList ``proveedores`` talvez estás pasando una lista vacía

Comment: @Joshin el metodo BuscarElemento es el de Buscar_proveedor, en lo cual tengo que pedir que digite un ID y que lo encuentre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 errores encontrados en tu método `buscar_proveedor`:

1. En tu clase `Proveedor` declaras idProveedor como entero, pero tu variable `Buscar` (las variables se escriben con minúscula) lo declaras como String.
2. `if(BuscarElemento(proveedores,Buscar))`, no muestras el código del método `BuscarElemento` o como leí en un comentario de @Alfabravo lo borraste.

He reestructurado tu método `buscar_proveedor`, seguramente se puede mejorar creando métodos aparte pero la idea es la misma

```
public static void buscar_proveedor() {        
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Creamos 2 objetos de Proveedor 
        Proveedor proveedor1= new Proveedor(1, "Razon Social 1", 2010098765, "Activo");
        Proveedor proveedor2= new Proveedor(2, "Razon Social 2", 2010098766, "Inactivo");
        //Agregamos los objetos al ArrayList proveedores
        proveedores.add(proveedor1);
        proveedores.add(proveedor2);
        
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println(" Buscar Proveedor");
        System.out.println(" ");
        int buscar;
        System.out.print("Ingrese el ID a buscar: ");
        buscar=teclado.nextInt();
        
        boolean encontrado=false;
        //Recorremos el ArrayList proveedores mediante un ForEach
        for(Proveedor p:proveedores){
          if(p.getIdprovedor()==buscar){
            encontrado=true;          
          } 
        } 
        
        //Verificamos si se encontró el proveedor
        if(encontrado){//si encontrado es true
            System.out.println("PROVEEDOR ENCONTRADO");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO EXISTE");
        }
    }
```

Cualquier duda, me comentas

Comment: Hola, estoy teniendo un problema al momento de querer llamar sus atributos de ese ID, de que cuando pongo "proveedores.get(buscar)" no me manda la razon social, el ruc o estado; 
 tengo cargado la data sintetica y varios metodos para eliminar, agregar, editar, etc.

Comment: @Aaron sería bueno que pongas el código en una nueva pregunta para poder ver como está creado tus métodos eliminar, agregar, editar,etc.